# How to change hover event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, blogs

I only show this data when the mouse hovers. How can I change the hover to show data automatically? When I use `show()` the code does not work.

```js
(function(e) {
  var t = function(e, t) {
    this.elem = e;
    this.settings = t;
    this.megaMenuHtml1();
    this.menulist = this.elem.find(".leftmenulist li a");
    this.menuHelper(this.elem);
    this.addEvents()
  };

  t.prototype = {
    regex: {
      islabel: new RegExp("/search/label/", "g"),
      issearch: new RegExp("[?&]q=", "g"),
      labelsearch: new RegExp("(//[^/]+)/search/label/([^/?&]+).*[?&]q=([^$&]+)(?:[^$]+)?", "g"),
      label: new RegExp("(//[^/]+)/search/label/([^/?&$]+)", "g"),
      search: new RegExp("(//[^/]+)/search/?[?&]q=(.*)", "g")
    },
    addEvents: function() {
      var t = this;
      this.menulist.hover(function() {
        if (e(this).data("menuloaded") !== "true") {
          t.li = e(this);
          t.url = t.li.attr("href");
          t.container = t.li.closest("ul").siblings("ul");
          t.vkk1()
        }
      }, function() {})
    },
    vkk1: function() {
      var t = this;
      this.getAJAXUrl();
      if (!this.ajaxUrl) return;
      this.ajaxcall = e.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: t.ajaxUrl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: t.ajaxData,
        beforeSend: function() {
          t.showLoader()
        },
        success: function(e) {
          t.hideLoader();
          t.addArrow();
          t.showPosts(e)
        },
      })
    },
    getAJAXUrl: function() {
      if (this.url) {
        var e = this;
        this.ajaxData = {
          alt: "json",
          "max-results": this.settings.postsNumber
        };

        this.url.search(this.regex.islabel) !== -1 && this.url.search(this.regex.issearch) !== -1 ? this.ajaxUrl = this.url.replace(this.regex.labelsearch, function(t, n, r, i) {
          e.ajaxData.q = i;
          return [n, "/feeds/posts/default/-/", r, "/"].join("")
        }) : this.url.search(this.regex.islabel) !== -1 && this.url.search(this.regex.issearch) === -1 ? this.ajaxUrl = this.url.replace(this.regex.label, function(t, n, r) {
          delete e.ajaxData.q;
          return [n, "/feeds/posts/default/-/", r, "/"].join("")
        }) : this.url.search(this.regex.islabel) === -1 && this.url.search(this.regex.issearch) !== -1 ? this.ajaxUrl = this.url.replace(this.regex.search, function(t, n, r) {
          e.ajaxData.q = r;
          return [n, "/feeds/posts/default"].join("")
        }) : this.ajaxUrl = !1
      } else this.ajaxUrl = !1
    },
    showLoader: function() {},
    hideLoader: function() {},
    showPosts: function(t) {
      var n = this,
        r = [],
        i, s, o;

      t.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t > 0 ? e.each(t.feed.entry,
        function(t, u) {
          i = u.title.$t;
          e.each(u.link, function(e, t) {
            t.rel === "alternate" ? s = t.href : s = "#"
          });
          o = u.media$thumbnail ? u.media$thumbnail.url.replace(/\/s72\-c\//, "/s200-c/") : n.settings.noThumbnail;
          r.push('<li><span class="thumb-container"><a title="', i, '" href="', s, '"><img alt="', i, '" src="', o, '"/><br />', i, "</a></span></li>")
        }) : r.push("<h5>", "No posts available.", "</h5>");
      this.container.html(r.join(""));
      this.menulist.removeData("menuloaded");
      this.li.data("menuloaded", "true")
    },
    addArrow: function() {},
    menuHelper: function(t) {},
    megaMenuHtml1: function() {
      this.elem.find("ul ul").remove();
      this.elem.addClass("megamenuid").find(">li").find("ul:first").addClass("leftmenulist").wrap(e("<div></div>", {
        "class": this.settings.divClass
      }));
      e("ul.leftmenulist").after(e("<ul></ul>", {
        "class": "rightmenulist"
      }))
    },
  };

  e.fn.megaBloggerMenu1 = function(n) {
    var r = {
        postsNumber: 4
      },
      i = e.extend({}, r, n);
    return this.each(function() {
      var n = new t(e(this), i)
    })
  }
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#megamenuid').megaBloggerMenu1({
    postsNumber: 4
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='megamenuid'>
  <li><a href='#'>Fashion</a>
    <ul>
      <li id='111'><a href='//sora-cart-soratemplates.blogspot.in/search/label/mens'>MEN</a></li>
      <li><a href='//sora-cart-soratemplates.blogspot.in/search/label/women'>WOMEN</a></li>
      <li><a href='//sora-cart-soratemplates.blogspot.in/search/label/kids'>KIDS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please take some time to format your code. The "Tidy" button within the snippet editor will do most of the work for you.

Comment: Can you repeat your question?

Comment: if mouse curser is on MEN, WOMEN, and kids then data show (post display) and code working,How to work code without hover?